# Forwarding a touchmove event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that sits on top of a horizontally scrollable element. When I scroll over this element I want to forward that scroll event to the scrollable element below, but when I click on it I want it to do something else.

```
$(".scroll-indicator").on("touchmove", function(evt){
    // forward scroll event to ".scrollable-element"
});

$(".scroll-indicator").on("click", function(evt){
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```

How can I forward the scroll event to my scrollable element?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function to manually fire an event on an specific element.